# Hardcoded variable names

Tags: hibernate, switch-statement

I'm currently undertaking training and I was assigned to write code for maintaining and persisting objects using `java` with hibernate and `sql DB`.

I have observed that in many situations I have to use switch statements with hardcoded variable names of persisted entities and I find this solution very hard to maintain and not flexible (I have all possible variables of my Vehicle class in at least 4 different classes).

I have suggested to my tutor, that maybe the solution would be to have final array of possible variable names and use it for iteration, but I've been told that this solution is bad (without further explanation).

I have tried to find good examples for my problem and yet I have failed.

My question is, what is the best solution to handle variables in situation like query, entity update etc?

**EDIT**

As requested I provide the example of code with which i have issue. Here is mine `Query` class

```
public class VehicleQueryCriteria extends QueryCriteria<DBVehicle> {
    private Object[] argumentValue = new Object[1];
    private String[] argumentName = new String[1];
    private CompareEnum[] relation = new CompareEnum[1];

    public VehicleQueryCriteria(String argumentName, CompareEnum relation, Object argumentValue){
        this.argumentValue[0] = argumentValue;
        this.relation[0] = relation;
        this.argumentName[0] = argumentName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getValues() {
        return this.argumentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getValueName() {
        return this.argumentName;
    }

    @Override
    public CompareEnum[] getRelations() {
        return this.relation;
    }
}
```

with one more method in abstract superclass

`public void accept(QueryVisitor<T> queryVisitor) {queryVisitor.visitQuery(this);}`

where query visitor creates validator object with following method

```
private static Validator<DBVehicle> parse(String argumentName, Object argumentValue, CompareEnum relation){
    switch (argumentName){
        case "id":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (UUID)argumentValue, DBVehicle::getId);
        case "vinNumber":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (String)argumentValue, DBVehicle::getVinNumber);
        case "productionDate":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (Date)argumentValue, DBVehicle::getProductionDate);
        case "plateNumber":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (String)argumentValue, DBVehicle::getPlateNumber);
        case "manufacturer":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (String)argumentValue, DBVehicle::getManufacturer);
        case "horsePower":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (Integer)argumentValue, DBTruck::getHorsePower);
        case "mileage":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (Integer)argumentValue, DBTruck::getMileage);
        case "volume":
            return VehicleValidator.create(relation, (Integer)argumentValue, DBTrailer::getVolume);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter name \"" + argumentName+ "\" is not valid Vehicle parameter");
    }
}
```

`CompareEnum` is enum containing set of comparators like `GREATER_THAN` and `EQUALS` and `Validator` is object with one method method `validate` which accepts "BDVehicle" and returns boolean. Both `Query` and `Validator` are scalable and can be easily aggregated in composite class, and I am quite pleased with this solution. The only thing that bothers me is this switch statement.

Comment: Have any code to share to illustrate your problem?

Comment: In the update method i use map (`<String, Object>`) containing parameters which i would like to update. In this method I need to validate those names against some hardcoded list of possible key values, and later i have switch with keys and function used to update entity. In other place I have my `QueryCriteria` class which holds similar information plus additionally some relation (greater, smaller, equal, etc.). And when I create hibernate `Query` object I have to use hardcoded parameter name once again. The more I work on code, the more those types of things propagate to different classes...

Comment: Some of your concerns could be resolved by using refactoring.  You might want to read up on Separation of Concerns, Single Responsibility Principle, and Design Patterns (such as Strategy Pattern).  Depending how you create your query strings, its pretty common that these be somewhat hard coded.  The method that wraps the query is typically well named, self-documenting to explain the expected inputs and the output, etc.  If you'd like more help, please update your post with your code so we can actually *see it*.